# new XMLHttpRequest() doesn't work in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I know it kind sounds silly ... it should work there ... but :

```
function fetch(id){
    var fetch = new XMLHttpRequest();
    fetch.open("GET", "/upload/status?X-Progress-ID=" + id);
    fetch.onreadystatechange = function () {
      console.log(fetch.readyState);
    }
    fetch.send(null);
}
```

This code works in IE , in firefox ... i get all 4 states returned ... but when i try it in chrome i get absolutely nothing ... and i have absolutely no idea why...

**I think you have already guessed the question , why it doesn't work ?**

**EDIT**:

Changed the code a little bit ...  As you have maybe already guessed , i work with nginx upload progress module , and this function is called everysecond to get the progress of the uploaded file ...

**EDIT 1**

Well i tried to rewrite the thing $.ajax() , and i basically got the same result .. ie , firefox works , and chrome just gives me nothing . Here is a full code of the page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="static/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    function add() {
      if (parseInt(document.getElementById('count').getAttribute('value')) < 8) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type','file');
        input.setAttribute('multiple','');
        input.setAttribute('name','file[]');
        document.getElementById('multiple').appendChild(input);
        document.getElementById('multiple').appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        document.getElementById('count').setAttribute('value',parseInt(document.getElementById('count').getAttribute('value'))+1);
      }
      else {
        alert('Можно загрузить не более 8 файлов за раз.');
      }
    }
    function progress() {
      var ms = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
      rq = 0;
      id = "";
      for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        id += Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16);
      }
      document.getElementById('upload').action = "/upload/share?X-Progress-ID=" + id;
//      console.log("/upload/share?X-Progress-ID=" + id);
      document.getElementById('status').style.display = 'block'
      interval = window.setInterval(function () { fetch(id, ms); }, 1000);
      return true;
    }
    function fetch(id, ms) {
//      console.log("/upload/status?X-Progress-ID=" + id);


      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/upload/status?X-Progress-ID="+id,
        dataType: 'text',
        complete: function(upload) {
          console.log('test');
          alert('test');
        }
      });

//      var fetch = new XMLHttpRequest();
//      fetch.open("GET", "/upload/status", 1);
//      fetch.setRequestHeader("X-Progress-ID", id);
//      fetch.open("GET", "/upload/status?X-Progress-ID=" + id);
//      fetch.setRequestHeader("X-Progress-ID", id);

//      fetch.onreadystatechange = function () {
//        console.log('rorororo');
//        console.log(fetch.readyState);
//        if (fetch.readyState == 3) {
//          console.log(fetch.responseText);
//
////          if (fetch.status == 200) {
//
//            var now = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
//            var upload = eval(fetch.responseText);
//
//            if (upload.state == 'uploading') {
//              var diff = upload.size - upload.received;
//              var rate = upload.received / upload.size;
//              var elapsed = now - ms;
//              var speed = upload.received - rq; rq = upload.received;
//              var remaining = (upload.size - upload.received) / speed;
//              var uReceived = parseInt(upload.received) + ' bytes';
//              var uDiff = parseInt(diff) + ' bytes';
//              var tTotal = parseInt(elapsed + remaining) + ' secs';
//              var tElapsed = parseInt(elapsed) + ' secs';
//              var tRemaining = parseInt(remaining) + ' secs';
//              var percent = Math.round(100*rate) + '%';
//              var uSpeed = speed + ' bytes/sec';
//              document.getElementById('length').firstChild.nodeValue = parseInt(upload.size) + ' bytes';
//              document.getElementById('sent').firstChild.nodeValue = uReceived;
//              document.getElementById('offset').firstChild.nodeValue = uDiff;
//              document.getElementById('total').firstChild.nodeValue = tTotal;
//              document.getElementById('elapsed').firstChild.nodeValue = tElapsed;
//              document.getElementById('remaining').firstChild.nodeValue = tRemaining;
//              document.getElementById('speed').firstChild.nodeValue = uSpeed;
//              document.getElementById('bar').firstChild.nodeValue = percent;
//              document.getElementById('bar').style.width = percent
//            }
//            else {
//              window.clearTimeout(interval);
//            }
////          }
//        }

//      }
//      fetch.send(null);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload" onsubmit="progress();">
  <input type="hidden" id="count" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" value="GOBLEBOELBOE" name="secret">
  <div id="multiple">
    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple /><br>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
  <a href="#" onclick="add();">add();</a>
</form>
<div id="status" style="display: none;">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr><th></th><th>загрузка</th><th>осталось</th><th>всего</th></tr>
    <tr><td>время:</td><td id="elapsed">∞</td><td id="remaining">∞</td><td id="total">∞</td></tr>
    <tr><td>размер:</td><td id="sent">0 b</td><td id="offset">0 b</td><td id="length">0 b</td></tr>
    <tr><td>скорость:</td><td id="speed">n/a</td></tr>
  </table>
  <div style="border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;">
    <div style="background: #c0c0c0; width: 0%; text-align: right;" id="bar">0%</div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('Вы точно хотите отменить загрузку?')) window.location = '/'" id="cancel">cancel_upload();</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**ANSWER:** http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45196

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is so bug with chrome.
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45196

Answer (score 0):

You should add this

```
fetch.send(null)
```

> open()
>
> Initializes a request. This method is to be used from JavaScript code; to initialize a request from native code, use openRequest()instead.
>
> send()
>
> Sends the request. If the request is asynchronous (which is the default), this method returns as soon as the request is sent. If the request is synchronous, this method doesn't return until the response has arrived.

Quoted from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest)

Comment: Is there any exception in console.

Comment: Look i edited  a code a little bit ... And no , there is absolutely no exception ... That's the main problem ..  It's is not called at all.... because if i  console.log some random string in here `fetch.onreadystatechange = function () {  }`   , it prinbts absolutely nothing....